# How to use output values of one function as input of another MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How would I go about using and assigning the values of my getValidArgs output into the input of my processArgs function. At the moment I have been able to get it to work somewhat but when I go to use one of the assigned values n,mu or sigma it says that the value is undefined. I will attach my code and the question I am trying to complete.

Thanks for your help.

```
function [n, mu, sigma] = getValidArgs( varargin )
[n, mu, sigma] = processArgs( varargin );
end

function [n, mu, sigma] = processArgs( args)

%args cell array

% Number of elements in arg less than 3
if length( args)<3
error('Required input for n, mu and sigma not provided')
end
```

end

Comment: Could you provide the code you managed to get to somewhat work?

Comment: Please actually post your code in your question.  Don't post images of your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated the question to contain the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
function [n,mu,si] = getValidArgs(a,b,c)

[n,mu,si] = processArgs(a,b,c);

end
function processArgs(varargin)

if length(varargin)
    error('edagagag')
end

if isscaler(varargin{1})||iscalar(varargin{2})||isscalar(varargin{3})
else
    error('dagdgg')
end
end
```

Comment: I tried using this and it works for the most part but for some reason the testing harness still can't identify what n is.

Comment: This is the testing harness: http://textuploader.com/pcwr

It should give a results similar to this but with different error messages.

    >> testGetValidArgs
    Test: N = 1; mu, sigma normal

    result = 

    error: []
        n: 1
       mu: 2
    sigma: 5

    Test: N > 1; mu, sigma normal

    result = 

    error: []
        n: 8
       mu: 1
    sigma: 3

    Test: Insufficient arguments

    result = 

    error: 'Three arguments are required: n, mu, sigma'
        n: []
       mu: []
    sigma: []

    Test: n < 0; mu, sigma OK